# What exactly does postman do when I check the "Request access token locally" checkbox?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, postman

I'm testing my oauth2 server, implemented with Spring (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth)

When I test the server with the "Request access token locally" checkbox selected it works if I test the server without the selected checkbox it does not work.

Can you tell me what exactly postman does when I select the "Request access token locally" checkbox?

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Truly baffling that this is not documented in the Postman documentation.